# Парсинг Json. Вывести если есть ключ

Tags: python, json, парсер, python-3.6

Необходимо спарсить Json. Парсинг происходит успешно, но есть 1 ключ, который в зависимости от устройства может присутствовать либо отсутствовать. Есть ли какой-то стандартный метод проверяющий на наличие ключа или необходимо писать свою функцию для проверки существования данного ключа в Json и вывода его значения если он существует?
Например:

```py
print('IMEI: ' + result['foo']['foo']['foo']['IMEI'])
```

Вот этот IMEI может быть, а может его не быть.

```py
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://foo") as url:
    json_data = json.loads(url.read())
    for result in json_data['foo']['foo']:
        print(' | IMEI: ' + result['foo']['foo']['foo']['IMEI'].keys())
```

Метод `keys()` не помогает

```py
def show_domain_device_info():
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://адрес" + str(id_number) + "адрес") as url:
            json_data = json.loads(url.read())
            print(type(json_data))
            for result in json_data['included']['data']:
                print('ID: ' + '{:50}'.format(result['bar']) +
                      ' | Статус: ' + result['foo1']['bar1'] +
                      ' | Имя: ' + result['foo1']['foo2']['bar1'] +
                      ' | Тип: ' + result['foo1']['foo2']['bar2'] +
                      ' | Класс: ' + result['foo1']['foo2']['bar3'] +
                      ' | IMEI: ' + result['foo1']['foo2'].get('IMEI', None)                     
                      )
    except IOError:
        print('Бла бла бла')
```

Пишет

> TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `.get`:

```
dct = {'a': {'b': {'ok': 'OK!'}}}

print('OK: ', dct['a']['b'].get('ok', None))
print('Fail: ', dct['a']['b'].get('fail', None))
```

Если `['b']` может иметь разный тип данных (ошибка `AttributeError: object has no attribute 'get'`), можно завернуть вывод в `if`:

```
if isinstance(result['a']['b'], dict):
```

Для отключения завершающего переноса строки у `print`:

```
print('строка', end='')
```

Для твоего примера:

```
def show_domain_device_info():
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://адрес" + str(id_number) + "адрес") as url:
            json_data = json.loads(url.read())
            print(type(json_data))
            for result in json_data['included']['data']:
                print('ID: ' + '{:50}'.format(result['bar']) +
                  ' | Статус: ' + result['foo1']['bar1'] +
                  ' | Имя: ' + result['foo1']['foo2']['bar1'] +
                  ' | Тип: ' + result['foo1']['foo2']['bar2'] +
                  ' | Класс: ' + result['foo1']['foo2']['bar3'], end='')
                if isinstance(result['foo1']['foo2'], dict):
                    print(' | IMEI: ', result['foo1']['foo2'].get('IMEI', None))
                else:
                    print(' | IMEI: ', None)
    except IOError:
        print('Бла бла бла')
```

Comment: Не помогает. Та же ошибка. Ругается что такого ключа нет

Comment: У меня такое чувство, что у тебя тут: `json_data['foo']['foo']` и тут `result['foo']['foo']['foo']` лишние "`foo`". И нет не ключа `IMEI`, а одного из "`foo`".

Comment: Лишнего foo нет. Подставляю устройство с IMEI, всё отображается корректно

Comment: Что выдает: `type(result['foo']['foo']['foo'])`, когда 'IMEI' нет?

Comment: Кучу данных. Вывод показать не могу. Лишнего foo нет. Подставляю устройство с IMEI, всё отображается корректно. Там много данных. Путь до imei правильный. Проблема в том, что если попадается устройство без этого IMEI, то ошибка

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' пишет если `  ' | IMEI: ' + result['foo']['foo']['foo']['IMEI'].get('IMEI', None) `

Comment: Ааа. не заметил type. сейчас проверю

Comment: блин, тогда не получится вывести справа в одну строку с другими данными. Библиотеку для работы с таблицами пока не хочу подключать

Comment: `else: print(' | IMEI: ', None)` Выводи...

Comment: Добавил вверх сам код. Как туда вписать это? Или придётся вывод менять?

Comment: get должен получить строку. А там пусто, нет imei

Comment: Тогда разве print не с новой строки будет? Хочу чтобы справа вывод был в той же строке

Comment: `' | Класс: ' + result['foo1']['foo2']['bar3'], end='')`. Обрати внимание на: `end=''` `print` не завершит строку переносом.

Comment: Ооо. Не знал. Спасибо

Comment: Сейчас проверю, если ок, отмечу решение)